# stop scheduled cron jobs while database is creating

Tags: cron, database, jobs

we have a multi cron jobs runing everyday on different hours. In sometime script is running too long and block database in time where we set up a new one. The problem is that, a new database is no longer creating from script(we must do all manual).

How can i stop/ freez/terminate all jobs on for example 4:00 am; wait until new database setup fine and run it again?

Comment: which database system? PostgreSQL? MySQL? SQLite? Something else?

Comment: We use a PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 0):

Modify your database setup process to drop a canary file into `/var/run` (e. g. `/var/run/db_freeze`) upon startup, and remove it upon completion.

Modify your `cron` jobs to immediately terminate upon startup if that file exists.

For example, for the long-running job:

```
#!/bin/bash
# long-running DB setup job
touch /var/run/db_freeze
trap 'rm -f /var/run/db_freeze' EXIT
do_stuff
```

And for the `cron` jobs:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -f /var/run/db_freeze ]]; then
    #  Bail due to process lock from long-running job
    exit 2
fi
do_stuff
exit 0
```

If you want to wait for the longer process to finish, and then kick it off, rather than `exit`ing, you can wait for the canary to go away:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ -f /var/run/db_freeze ]]; do
    sleep 30
done
do_stuff
```

Note, however, that without working on locking the cron jobs themselves, if the long process goes longer than one `cron` cycle, you could end up with two concurrent instances of the `cron` job waiting to jump into action.

Comment: Thx, i try it tomorrow.

Comment: That actually makes the cron job exit, not wait, when the other process is still running. I agree that that might be better, but it's not what the OP asked ;-)

Comment: I will add the other way as an alternative option.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you can check what other processes are running by way of the [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) system view. If you can recognize your long-running process from that, you could start your cron job by checking that table. If it has an entry for the long-running process, wait. You can poll the database every so often, or you could use the [LISTEN/NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-notify.html) to signal that the database is now ready (this may require changes to both scripts though)

The advantage of this method is that it works if both scripts aren't running on the same machine, but it may be a bit more complex to set up properly.